# Java Date for Sql insert

Tags: java, sql, date, h2

I was trying to insert a date into oracle database but I keep facing an conversion issue.

```
public List<Customer> getCustomerData(Date start, Date end) {
...
String query = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE trunc(order_timestamp) between trunc(?) and trunc(?)";

DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
pst.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(sdf.format(start)).getTime()));

pst.setDate(2,  new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(sdf.format(end)).getTime()));

}
```

From the caller I have

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date start = sdf.parse("10/10/2014");
Date end = sdf.parse("10/10/2016");
customerDao.getCustomerData(start,end);
```

Error I got was:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "2014-10-10"; SQL statement:
select name from customers where trunc(order_timestamp) between trunc(?) and trunc(?)  [22018-160]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:852)
    at org.h2.engine.FunctionAlias$JavaMethod.getValue(FunctionAlias.java:366)
    at org.h2.expression.JavaFunction.getValue(JavaFunction.java:38)
    at org.h2.expression.Comparison.getValue(Comparison.java:206)
    at org.h2.expression.ConditionAndOr.getValue(ConditionAndOr.java:83)
    at org.h2.expression.ConditionAndOr.getValue(ConditionAndOr.java:90)
    at org.h2.expression.Expression.getBooleanValue(Expression.java:180)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:514)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:617)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:298)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:268)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:37)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:82)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:185)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at com.customerDaoImpl.custDao.getParentContextdata(custDao.java:431)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2014-10-10"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:831)
    ... 44 more
```

what I think happened was that getTime() will reformat the date into yyyy-MM-dd format and while the input was n MM/dd/yyyy format. But I am not sure if this is exactly what cause the issue.

Edit:
H2 doesnt support trunc but you are able to write external script to be invoked.

in `Customer.sql`

```
drop ALIAS if exists TRUNC;
CREATE ALIAS TRUNC as '
import java.text.*;
@CODE
double trunc(double num) throws Exception {
    return Math.floor(num*10) /10;
}
';
```

Comment: You need another format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) or helper method that would try parsing by multiple formats is you're not sure about exact format of input.

Comment: getTime() returns a number of milliseconds. How could it reformat anything. Post the **complete** exception stack trace.

Comment: Sounds like you need two DateFormats: One for "yyyy-MM-dd" and another for "MM/dd/yyyy".  getTime() returns milliseconds since epoch as a long.  No formatting at all.

Comment: The error is explicit: you're sending dates as `"yyyy-MM-dd"` and your pattern is `"MM/dd/yyyy"`. How do you expect this to work?

Comment: My question would be why would you do this: `pst.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(sdf.format(start)).getTime()));` when you could do this: `pst.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(start.getTime()));`?

Comment: @AlinPandichi the error is the same. I was trying to make it into the MM/dd/yyyy format...

Answer (score 3):

You're not using Oracle at all, as the stack trace shows. You're using H2. 
And H2 doesn't seem to have any `trunc` function accepting a date as argument.

This function call is useless anyway, since you're already passing a date, without any time portion, as argument. The trunc operation, if it existed, would do nothing.

Comment: That's the problem with this strategy: you end up with tests which pass although they would fail with the real production database, and vice-versa. Don't know why so many people prefer that over losing a few seconds targetting the real database.

Comment: updated: as for trunc you are able to write script functions and the database will call that function i have added it to the edit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP is expected, so use `Timestamp` instead of sql `Date`. A `java.sql.Date` is for days only, setting the parent's class hours, minutes and seconds to zero.

Comment: Data conversion error converting "2014-10-10 00:00:00.0". It still presists

Answer (score 0):

Your external `trunc` script expects a `double` as an input, but you're passing a `java.sql.Date`. Try this for the script:

```
drop ALIAS if exists TRUNC;
CREATE ALIAS TRUNC as '
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.Date;
@CODE
double trunc(Date date) throws Exception {
    return Math.floor(new Long(date.getTime()).doubleValue()*10) / 10;
}
';
```

Although I suspect you would then get another error complaining that you are trying to compare `double` values with `between`. Shouldn't your `trunc` script return a Date too? If it should, then just return the Date:

```
drop ALIAS if exists TRUNC;
CREATE ALIAS TRUNC as '
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.Date;
@CODE
Date trunc(Date date) throws Exception {
    return date;
}
';
```

If that works, you can later evolve this script to apply any other operations you want on the `date` to simulate your trunc behaviour.

For the record, here is the H2 code that is converting your Date into the "yyyy-MM-dd" pattern: [ValueDate.java#158](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.h2database/h2/1.4.187/org/h2/value/ValueDate.java#158).
The string value is stored here [Value.java#827](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.h2database/h2/1.4.187/org/h2/value/Value.java#827) and then used by the Double parser method here: [Value.java#876](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.h2database/h2/1.4.187/org/h2/value/Value.java#876)